PowerPC stb instruction in c implementation
I'm trying to store high 24-32 byte of integer to char pointer address, Which is stb r9 0(r30) ,
How to use C implement this behavior?

In C, you don't program stores – that's the job of the underlying assembler implementation, as generated by the compiler.
But if you say you need to save the upper 8 bits of a 32 bit variable var to some address stored in the pointer p, then that's just a job for a normal bit mask
*p = var & 0xFF000000;

Explanation



code construct in C     
meaning




*p
dereference p, i.e., do this to the address stored in p


=
assign the value on the right to what is on the                   left (i.e., the reference to the address stored in p)


var & 0xFF000000
Take the bit-wise AND of the value in var and 0xFF000000, which is in binary eight 1s followed by twenty-four 0s.



It's the C compiler's job to convert that into an adequate store instruction. And as this example compilation shows, it will just do exactly that!

Hi, guru ,it doesn't work on powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc , still not produced stb as c behavior.
